# Angular 2 Communication over a service without using a Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive

I am wondering if I could solve the following scenario without a Subject. I have two components: The first component creates a hero and the other component displays a hero. Those components communicate over a service. Currently I have the following solution:

**Hero Creation**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-creation',
  ....
})
export class HeroCreation{

  constructor(private heroSercice: HeroService){
  }

  onClick(){
     this.heroSercice.addHero();
  }
}
```

**Hero Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
public hero$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
  }

  public addHero(hero: string): void {
    this.hero$.next(hero);
  }
}
```

**Hero Display**

```
@Component({
selector: 'hero-display',
....
})
export class HeroDisplay{

  constructor(private heroSercice: HeroService){
    //Use async pipe in template to display the hero
    this.heros$ = this.heroSercice.hero$
  }
}
```

The goal would be to implement the same feature just with plain Observables without using a subject.

Comment: Since you're adding new heroes in `addHero()` which is based on some user action I don't think you can avoid using a Subject.

Comment: Could you maybe state why you would want to do this? Because the thing is, that you cannot simply emit data on just any observable - there WOULD be technically other ways I guess, but I would not recommend those. - If you don't want to stick to pure rxjs have a look at ngrx

Comment: Theoretically you could use `Observable.fromEvent().map()` instead of Angular's `(click)` but that would just make things more complicated.

Comment: And... what's the reasoning for this? The whole purpose of subjects is that they can expose `next` method, so new values could be added from the outside.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is a way to implement this without a subject. When I am using pure RxJs without Angular theres almost no scenario where I need a subject. Using Observables instead of subject is a much more declarative way. By using subject with manually calling next feels very imperative to me.

Comment: Is there routing involved here, or just a master-detail type of solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for a subject.

> The Subject class inherits both Observable and Observer, in the sense that it is both an observer and an observable.

After `hero$` observable was created, new values should be added to it somehow. And they should be added through observer. Without a subject, an observer has to be exposed manually in order to reach it:

```
protected _heroObserver: Observer<string>;
public hero$: Observable<string> = Observable.create<string>(observer => {
    this._heroObserver = observer;
});
...
public addHero(hero: string): void {
    this._heroObserver.next(hero);
}
```

And this is exactly what subjects are supposed to do. Since `addHero` acts as a setter, exposing a subject as public property breaks encapsulation. In order to preserve encapsulation it is possible to expose only `hero$` observable instead:

```
protected _heroSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
public hero$: Observable<string> = this._heroSubject.asObservable();
...
public addHero(hero: string): void {
    this._heroSubject.next(hero);
}
```